# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString') and giving error which i am unable to understand

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
require("dotenv").config;

async function main() {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
  const encryptedJsonkey = await wallet.encrypt(
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD,
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
  );
  console.log(encryptedJsonkey);
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });



and the terminal run out this......

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')
    at isHexable (c:\Users\rs851\OneDrive\Desktop\ether-simple-
```

how to solve this error I have go through every possible solution but nothing work. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

even I was facing the same issue yesterday.
Try to downgrade the ethers to **"5.5.3"**.